# How to catch tree node clicks from a (MVC) controller in ExtJs 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

In my ExtJS 4 controllers I can catch events on certain elements on the page.
For example, to catche menu items clicks I can do:

```
init: function() { 
    this.control({
        'maintoolbar menuitem[action=contacts]': {
            click: function() {
                                // do something ;
                            }
                    }
            }).......
```

How do I do the same to catch tree node clicks? I pretty much want the same effect as the menu item (the tree has the id of settingstree).

EDIT: here's the tree code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.system.SettingsTree',{
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    requires: [ 
            'Ext.data.TreeStore',
            'MyApp.store.SettingsTree',
    ],
    title: MyApp.locale.T('settings'),
    defaults: {
            expanded:true
    }, 
    id:'settingstree',
    store: Ext.create('MyApp.store.SettingsTree'),
    alias: 'widget.settingstree',
    rootVisible: false,
    useArrows: true,
    /*listeners: {
            itemclick: function(view, record, el, index, ev, options ) {
                    console.log(arguments);
            }
    }*/
 });
```

Note that I intentionally commented out the itemclick listener. While this does report me on ll nodes clicked, I prefer to catch that in the controller, as I should...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Would be helpful if you can share the code where you build your Tree :)

Comment: Lionel, tree code added to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put:

```
this.control({
        'settingstree': {
            itemclick: function() {
                                // do something ;
                            }
                    }
            })
```

in appropriate controller

Comment: Thanks! I nearly had it, but was trying it with 'click' instead of 'itemclick'. I was hoping to get a similar behaviour to a menu item where it sends the action to the controller, but I mimicked that by adding a property 'action' to the model and getting it from the record.