# ExtJS 4.1 controller handling Tree node click event

Tags: javascript, extjs, controller, treepanel

Having trouble and not sure how to proceed with debug.  Found a question that looks almost exactly like mine, however the solution doesn't work: [How to catch tree node clicks from a (MVC) controller in ExtJs 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871293/how-to-catch-tree-node-clicks-from-a-mvc-controller-in-extjs-4)

The only difference I can see between that question and mine is that my tree is created directly within my layout as an item object using `xtype` of `treepanel` where that one is created separately.

Here is my controller:

```
Ext.define("IOL.controller.app.AppLayout", {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'app toolbar > button[itemId=filter]' : {
                click: this.onFilter
            },
            'menuTree': {
                itemclick: this.onFilter
            }
        });
    },

    onFilter: function(btn) {
        alert('test');
        Ext.create('IOL.view.app.Home').show();
    }

});
```

Here is the relevant item from my view:

```
{
        xtype: 'treepanel',
        title: 'Navigation',
        split: true,
        collapsible: true,
        margins: '5 0 5 5',
        region: 'west',
        width: 170,
        id: 'menuTree',
        alias: 'widget.menuTree',
        store: Ext.create('IOL.store.app.AppNav'),
        useArrows: true,
        rootVisible: false
        /*listeners : {
            itemdblclick : function(view,rec,item,index,eventObj) {

                console.log(view);
                console.log(rec);
                console.log(item);
                console.log(index);
                console.log(eventObj);
                if(rec.get('leaf') == true){
                    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('tabpanel')[0].add({
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: rec.get('text'),
                        itemId: rec.get('id'),
                        //url: 'server/HomeTab/read.php',
                        html : 'test content name: ' + rec.get('id'),
                        closable : true
                    });
                }

            }
        }*/
    }
```

The control for the button `app toolbar > button[itemId=filter]` works, however assigning the same action to the 'menuTree' does not work.  Browser console brings back a valid object with `Ext.getCmp('menuTree')` so I'm lost as to why the controller does not seem to be acting on the tree.

The tree is loading from a store, which makes me wonder if this is a similar scenario to where one would need to use `.on('click')` rather than `.click()` in jQuery...almost like the controller is not seeing the tree (but sees the button in the same view?).  I purposely commented out the handler directly on the tree (which does work).

Can provide all the files if it would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ext.getCmp() returns components by *id*, while Controllers use Ext.ComponentQuery.query() syntax to find their components; so effectively you're trying to control a component with xtype menuTree that doesn't exist. You should use either '#menuTree' or 'treepanel' as your selector.

Comment: Awesome! for some reason using 'treepanel' still doesn't work but #menuTree works like a charm.  Didn't realize that was allowed in controllers. Thanks!

Comment: Read up on [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery), it's worth it and more.